# H.264 video streaming with AVFoundation on OS X?

Tags: macos, video-streaming, avfoundation, h.264, video-encoding

Based on [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980070/how-to-use-avsamplebufferdisplaylayer-in-ios-8-for-rtp-h264-streams-with-gstream) and Apple's [Direct Access to Video Encoding and Decoding](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#513), from WWDC 2014, I've made a small Xcode-project that demonstrates how to decode and display a H.264 stream with *AVFoundation*. The project is available on github [here](https://github.com/niswegmann/H264Streamer).

I've dumped a series of 1000 NALUs into files and included them in the project (*nalu_000.bin* ... *nalu_999.bin*).

The interesting part of the code, that parses the NALUs and streams them to the *AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer*, is included below:

```
@import AVKit;

typedef enum {
    NALUTypeSliceNoneIDR = 1,
    NALUTypeSliceIDR = 5,
    NALUTypeSPS = 7,
    NALUTypePPS = 8
} NALUType;

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) VideoView * videoView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData * spsData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData * ppsData;
@property (nonatomic) CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef videoFormatDescr;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL videoFormatDescriptionAvailable;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (VideoView *)videoView {
    return (VideoView *) self.view;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];

    if (self) {
        _videoFormatDescriptionAvailable = NO;
    }

    return self;
}

- (int)getNALUType:(NSData *)NALU {
    uint8_t * bytes = (uint8_t *) NALU.bytes;

    return bytes[0] & 0x1F;
}

- (void)handleSlice:(NSData *)NALU {
    if (self.videoFormatDescriptionAvailable) {
        /* The length of the NALU in big endian */
        const uint32_t NALUlengthInBigEndian = CFSwapInt32HostToBig((uint32_t) NALU.length);

        /* Create the slice */
        NSMutableData * slice = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:&NALUlengthInBigEndian length:4];

        /* Append the contents of the NALU */
        [slice appendData:NALU];

        /* Create the video block */
        CMBlockBufferRef videoBlock = NULL;

        OSStatus status;

        status =
            CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock
                (
                    NULL,
                    (void *) slice.bytes,
                    slice.length,
                    kCFAllocatorNull,
                    NULL,
                    0,
                    slice.length,
                    0,
                    & videoBlock
                );

        NSLog(@"BlockBufferCreation: %@", (status == kCMBlockBufferNoErr) ? @"successfully." : @"failed.");

        /* Create the CMSampleBuffer */
        CMSampleBufferRef sbRef = NULL;

        const size_t sampleSizeArray[] = { slice.length };

        status =
            CMSampleBufferCreate
                (
                    kCFAllocatorDefault,
                    videoBlock,
                    true,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    _videoFormatDescr,
                    1,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    1,
                    sampleSizeArray,
                    & sbRef
                );

        NSLog(@"SampleBufferCreate: %@", (status == noErr) ? @"successfully." : @"failed.");

        /* Enqueue the CMSampleBuffer in the AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer */
        CFArrayRef attachments = CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray(sbRef, YES);
        CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = (CFMutableDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(attachments, 0);
        CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately, kCFBooleanTrue);

        NSLog(@"Error: %@, Status: %@",
              self.videoView.videoLayer.error,
                (self.videoView.videoLayer.status == AVQueuedSampleBufferRenderingStatusUnknown)
                    ? @"unknown"
                    : (
                        (self.videoView.videoLayer.status == AVQueuedSampleBufferRenderingStatusRendering)
                            ? @"rendering"
                            :@"failed"
                      )
             );

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            [self.videoView.videoLayer enqueueSampleBuffer:sbRef];
            [self.videoView.videoLayer setNeedsDisplay];
        });

        NSLog(@" ");
    }
}

- (void)handleSPS:(NSData *)NALU {
    _spsData = [NALU copy];
}

- (void)handlePPS:(NSData *)NALU {
    _ppsData = [NALU copy];
}

- (void)updateFormatDescriptionIfPossible {
    if (_spsData != nil && _ppsData != nil) {
        const uint8_t * const parameterSetPointers[2] = {
            (const uint8_t *) _spsData.bytes,
            (const uint8_t *) _ppsData.bytes
        };

        const size_t parameterSetSizes[2] = {
            _spsData.length,
            _ppsData.length
        };

        OSStatus status =
            CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets
                (
                    kCFAllocatorDefault,
                    2,
                    parameterSetPointers,
                    parameterSetSizes,
                    4,
                    & _videoFormatDescr
                );

        _videoFormatDescriptionAvailable = YES;

        NSLog(@"Updated CMVideoFormatDescription. Creation: %@.", (status == noErr) ? @"successfully." : @"failed.");
    }
}

- (void)parseNALU:(NSData *)NALU {
    int type = [self getNALUType: NALU];

    NSLog(@"NALU with Type \"%@\" received.", naluTypesStrings[type]);

    switch (type)
    {
        case NALUTypeSliceNoneIDR:
        case NALUTypeSliceIDR:
            [self handleSlice:NALU];
            break;
        case NALUTypeSPS:
            [self handleSPS:NALU];
            [self updateFormatDescriptionIfPossible];
            break;
        case NALUTypePPS:
            [self handlePPS:NALU];
            [self updateFormatDescriptionIfPossible];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)streamVideo:(id)sender {
    NSBundle * mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
        NSString * resource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"nalu_%03d", k];
        NSString * path = [mainBundle pathForResource:resource ofType:@"bin"];
        NSData * NALU = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [self parseNALU:NALU];
    }
}

@end
```

Basically the code works as follows:

1. It creates a *CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef* from the SPS and PPS NALUs with *CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateFromH264ParameterSets*.
2. It re-packages the NALUs according to the AVCC format. Since the NALU start codes have already been removed it just prepends a 4-byte NALU length header (in big-endian).
3. It packages all VLC NALU frames as *CMSampleBuffers* and feeds them to an *AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer*.

The code seems to read the SPS and the PPS parameter sets correctly. Unfortunately when feeding the *CMSampleBuffers* to the *AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer* something goes wrong. For each frame Xcode dumps the following messages in the log-window (the program doesn't crash):

```
[16:05:22.533] <<<< VMC >>>> vmc2PostDecodeError: posting DecodeError (-8969) -- PTS was nan = 0/0
[16:05:22.534] vtDecompressionDuctDecodeSingleFrame signalled err=-8969 (err) (VTVideoDecoderDecodeFrame returned error) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia_frameworks/CoreMedia-1562.235/Sources/VideoToolbox/VTDecompressionSession.c line 3241
[16:05:22.535] <<<< VMC >>>> vmc2DequeueAndDecodeFrame: frame failed - err -8969
```

Furthermore, the frames look like weird Monet-paintings:

[image: Monet 2]

I'm no expert at the H.264 format (or video encoding/decoding in general) and would appreciate if someone with a better grasp of this topic would take a look at the demo project and perhaps point me in the right direction.

I'll leave the code on github in the future as an example for other people who are interested in decoding H.264 on OS X/iOS.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, and also looking for a solution. Mine is actually worse, because I can't see anything drawn.

Comment: Error -8969 typically occur (in my experience) when your extradata (what you pass in kVDADecoderConfiguration_avcCData when creating the decoder) doesn't match the data stream.

Comment: How about to resolve vtDecompressionDuctDecodeSingleFrame signalled err=-8969

Comment: Have you found the solution to this yet?

Comment: Have you guys managed to solve it? I have the same issues